Can I use hash partitioning on a non-primary key column in a PostgreSQL table?
I am trying to replace an existing table with a partitioned version of that table. I want the schema of the new partitioned table to exactly match the existing non-partitioned table so that I can continue to manage the table through Django migrations.
My first attempt at creating the new partitioned table looked something like this:
CREATE TABLE partition_test (
    row_index bigint,
    id character varying(128) PRIMARY KEY,
    vendor_id character varying(128)
) PARTITION BY HASH (vendor_id);

Which results in the following error:
ERROR:  unique constraint on partitioned table must include all partitioning columns
DETAIL:  PRIMARY KEY constraint on table "product_api_partition_test" lacks column "vendor_id" which is part of the partition key.

I am looking for a work around that will allow me to partition on vendor_id while keeping row_index as the primary key.
I tried modifying the primary key as follows, however, Django requires a primary key and does not support composite primary keys. Therefore, both of these options would result in an inconsistency between the true schema and what Django believes is the schema.
CREATE TABLE partition_test (
    row_index bigint,
    id character varying(128),
    vendor_id character varying(128)
    PRIMARY KEY (row_index, vendor_id)
) PARTITION BY HASH (vendor_id);

CREATE TABLE api_partition_test (
    row_index bigint,
    id character varying(128),
    vendor_id character varying(128)
) PARTITION BY HASH (vendor_id);


There is no workaround. Best is to create primary keys on the partitions. If Django is so limited that it cannot deal with that, use something else (or a different database).

Why do you need table partitioning? A single table can have hundreds of millions of records and be really fast. And ORM's like Django are a real PITA when you need high performance anyway, most of the ORM's don't support the specific tricks you can do to speed up your database. Table partitioning is now one of the first issues you encounter
